# How to avoid error if textbox is empty?

Tags: c#

I'm looking for a solution to avoid an error if one or both of the textboxes are empty? I have tested to check if the value of height and width is null, but that I can only do after the code, and then it's to late!? Help is preciated! Thanks!

```
// Get values from text boxes
int height = Convert.ToInt32(txtInputA.Text);
int width = Convert.ToInt32(txtInputB.Text);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you’re trying to parse the user input as integer, you need to check for more than just empty strings. What if the input contains non-numeric characters? What if the number is too large?

The easiest way to validate all this would be through [`Int32.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx), which checks validity *and* performs the conversion (if valid) in a single call:

```
int height, width;
if (int.TryParse(txtInputA.Text, out height) == false)
    // Alert: invalid height.
if (int.TryParse(txtInputB.Text, out width) == false)
    // Alert: invalid width.
```

**Edit**: By the commented “Alert”, I’m assuming that you will throw some exception that will then be caught (by a calling method) and displayed to the user. If you’re going to display the error message directly from the above logic, then make sure to stop executing the method (e.g. through a `return` statement) following an unsuccessful conversion.

Comment: At Alert I call a method that show a message box, and then I have a break after the call to the method. Is that ok?

Comment: If you have an enclosing loop or switch statement, then yes.

Comment: In that case, it’s ok to use a break provided that you want to continue executing whatever code comes _after_ the switch statement, even in the case of an invalid height/width.

Comment: I guess with a break like this it leaves the rest of the code for the selected CASE where the is statement was? And then it continue to check for oter cases in the switch statement? Is there a better way?

Comment: If the method containing the logic is itself an event handler (say, for the `Click` event of a button), then I would just use a `return;` statement to stop executing it. (A `break;` would cause execution to leave the `switch { … }` block, but continue executing thereafter, which may not be what you want.)

Comment: if (!int.TryParse(txtInputA.Text, out height)) I think is cleaner.

Comment: @cinek: I don’t agree, since the `!` is easy to miss when skimming through code, but it’s a matter of personal preference. Both options are acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
  string aText = string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtInputA.Text)?"0":txtInputA.Text;
  int height = Convert.ToInt32(aText);
```

or you can do it like:

```
  int height = 0;
  int.TryParse(txtInputA.Text, out height);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is how you can check if the `TextBox` is not Empty :

```
int height;
int width;
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtInputA.Text) & !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtInputB.Text))
{
    // Get values from text boxes
    height = Convert.ToInt32(txtInputA.Text);
    width = Convert.ToInt32(txtInputB.Text);
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Height and Width!");
}
```

Comment: @DownVoter Any Problem with the code?? Please Explain this so that i can learn more!!!